# Form Layout in Qt for Android

Tags: android, qt

Does anybody know how to setup a nice form layout for a Qt form on Android? I'm new to Qt (coming from Delphi/C++ Builder) where I use simple control alignment to create forms / dialos that scale with the size of the window.

For example, when I draw an "OK" button on the lower left corner, it looks fine on Windows / Linux desktop, but it is incredible small when I change the build target to my Galaxy S4 (deployment works fine).
Thanks!

Comment: please post  your screenshot

Comment: no idea hot to post a screenshot here :-(

Comment: 1. Press `edit` (you can find it under tags) to update your original post
2. There is a button with image-like icon. Click it, then you can upload your screenshot

Comment: Yes, but stackoverflows says "You need at leas 10 reputations to post images". :-(

Comment: OK, I managed it by uploading to a website. Here ist a screenshot / comaprison: http://www.informance.at/Kontakt/sover.html

Answer (score -1):

You need to call

```
ui->button->adjustSize();
```

before `show();`

or just place all controls in layout